# DC/AC Converter using Motors

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, converter

I have two motors:

- One from a DVD player and
- Stepper motor.

I was wondering, if I use the DVD player motor to spin the stepper motor will I get an alternating current?

Comment: If you have a broad enough definition of what AC is then yes. If you mean 50/60 Hz sinusodial AC, then no.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I wanted to know I don't care much for the frequency yet.

Comment: Or the sine waveform yet.

Comment: @winny should be an answer, not a comment!

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It will just get downvoted and/or marked for deletion.

Comment: @winny hm. Doesn't seem that way.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Depends on who answers. Some just checks the screen name and if the points are <5k -> downvote and complain. I don't have energy for that and comments can't be downvoted but helps the OP equally much.

Comment: @winny but not posting answers will a) hurt the SE ecosystem in the middle and long run, and b) it's hard to gain reputation if you don't risk an answer. Seriously, if your answer gets downvoted to oblivion, and I *have* downvoted a lot of answers, it's usually not because of current reputation, and you can still just delete your two-line answer if that happens. No significant additional work.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Possibly, but the SE ecosystem suffers far more on EE.SE by the few people who go haywire on cracking down on new members, even if the answer is correct. I have not noticed it elsewhere on SE. You seem like a nice guy so I have no issues there. I'm here to help the people who ask questions and the SE is just a mean, not a goal in itself.

Comment: @winny I find your claims to not be backed by facts, sorry. And personally, I think this site will actually only prosper if there's good *answers*, not comments.

Comment: @winny at any rate, please do get active if you see such a case of people being discriminated against on a reputation basis! Meta.SE will be an excellent place to mention that.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a broad enough definition of what AC is then yes. If you mean 50/60 Hz sinusoidal AC, then no. – winny 2 hours ago